# Nhibernate could not deserialize a serializable property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a table in sql class which have to columns one is ID and another one is fImage. datatype of fImage column is Image. I am using nhibernate to load all images and want to bind it into picture box control. But we are getting exception when reading data using nhibernate that **nhibernate could not deserialize a serializable property** .

I went through some links on stackoverflow and google but nothing seems to be work for me.

Here I am giving sample hbm file and class file.

```
namespace BlackOpsP2.Core.Domain.ARModule
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Documentation for the tARReportLogo.
/// </summary>
public partial class tARReportLogo : DomainObject<System.Guid>
{
    #region Constructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="tARReportLogo"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public tARReportLogo()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="tARReportLogo"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fReportLogoID">The Payment Type ID.</param>
    public tARReportLogo(System.Guid fReportLogoID)
    {
        this.ID = fReportLogoID;
    }

    #endregion        

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets ReportLogoID.
    /// </summary> 
    public virtual System.Guid fReportLogoID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Image ID.
    /// </summary> 
    public virtual System.Guid fImageID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Image Name.
    /// </summary> 
    public virtual string fImageName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Image Value.
    /// </summary> 
    public virtual Image fImageValue { get; set; }                

    #endregion

    #region Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Joins a first name and a last name together into a single string.
    /// </summary>    
    /// <returns>The hash code.</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID.GetHashCode();
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

And here is hbm file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping assembly="BlackOpsP2.Core" namespace="BlackOpsP2.Core.Domain.ARModule" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="tARReportLogo" table="tARReportLogo" lazy="true" >
     <id name="fReportLogoID">
        <generator class="guid" />
     </id>    
     <property name="fImageID">
     </property>
     <property name="fImageName" >     
     </property>
     <property name="fImageValue" type="Serializable" length="2147483647">
     </property>    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am using nhibernate version 3.3.

Thanks,

Comment: {"The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 42-4D-DE-19-00-00-00-00-00-00-36-04-00-00-28-00-00 ..."}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your C# property to `byte[]`

```
public partial class tARReportLogo : DomainObject<System.Guid>
{
  ...
  public virtual byte[] fImageValue { get; set; }  // image as a byte array
  ...
}
```

And your mapping doesn't need more then this

```
<property name="fImageValue" length="2147483647" />
```

Any other conversions (to Image instance or whatever) you can do in C#. NHiberante will correclty map `byte[]` into SQL Server `image`

Comment: when we change type from image to byte[] then we are not able to bind Image with picturebox contro. I am using databinding property to bind image in PictureBox control.

Comment: It is just a DB part. The mapping of the DB `image` type into C# type `byte[]`. You can mark it as a protected : `protected virtual byte[] fImageValue { get; set; }` and introduce the  `public Image ImageValue { get {..} set {..} }` which will wrap calls to *fImageValue* and provide conversions. make sense?